# Error: Expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

Tags: c, arduino

I'm currently programming in the C language, and got this error. It occurs at line two. Here's my code:

```
const int LED = 13;
const int BUTTON = 7;

int val = 0

void setup() {
    pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(BUTTON, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
    val = digitalRead(BUTTON);

    if (val == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    } else { 
        digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a ```;``` after ```int val```

Comment: @LucasVirgili can you post your comment as an answer so this question can be marked as answered?

Comment: You didn't even make the effort of marking the answer as accepted. Shame of you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `;` after `int val`.